# gmtime() throw Segmentation fault (core dumped) in linux 64bit

Tags: c, archlinux

Today, I made some test with C's lib time.h in Manjaro Linux (64bit).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    time_t localtime;
    time(&localtime);

    printf("local time: %s", ctime(&localtime));

    struct tm * utcTime = gmtime(&localtime);
    time_t gmtTime = mktime(utcTime);

    printf("local time: %s", ctime(&gmtTime));
    return 0;
}
```

I build it successfully, but when I run it, line `struct tm * utcTime = gmtime(&localtime);` throws an exception:

```
local time: Tue Oct 14 13:22:41 2014
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I'm using Manjaro 64bit (Openbox), build with gcc 4.9.1. Do you know about this problem ? When I try it in window, it's fine.

Comment: Use a debugger and/or valgrind to pinpoint the problem.  Your code works fine on my Linux system.

Comment: Using `localtime` as a variable name is not a good idea. This is the name of a standard function.

Comment: Can't reproduce your error here, either. Works fine with different versions of gcc and clang. Please use the help channels of your Linux distribution to report your problem. Voting to close, because the error is not reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. I tested it with Manjaro Linux, gcc 4.9.2, clang 3.5.0 and valgrind. The crash means that either you're not showing your original code, or there's some problem elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer somewhere. 
Here's [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33703120/5368659)!
I fisrtly include `sys/time.h` but the complier doesn't recognize it and it returns a value of `int`. So it is necessary to include `time.h` so that the compiler can recognize `ctime` function.

Comment: If that is true then the compiler should have given warnings/errors when you compiled your original code