# Ubuntu Semaphore: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, pointers, ubuntu, semaphore

I am learning semaphores in C using Ubuntu right now. The professor just throw us this code and ask us to study it and observe. When I compiled I get a warning that `ctime(&sem_buf.sem_ctime)` returns an `int`, not a `char *` but nothing major. When I run it the output is just: `Semaphore identifier: 0    Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. I am very confused as of what went wrong and I have no idea what is going on in this code. Some help would be very much appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h> 
# define NS 3
union semun { 
   int val; 
   struct semid_ds *buf; 
   ushort *array; // Unsigned short integer.
}; 

int main(void) 
{ 
   int sem_id, sem_value, i; 
   key_t ipc_key; 
   struct semid_ds sem_buf; 
   static ushort sem_array[NS] = {3, 1, 4}; 
   union semun arg; 
   ipc_key = ftok(".", 'S'); // Creating the key.
   /* Create semaphore */ 
   if ((sem_id = semget(ipc_key, NS, IPC_CREAT | 0666)) == -1) { 
      perror ("semget: IPC | 0666"); 
      exit(1); 
   } 
   printf ("Semaphore identifier %d\n", sem_id); 
   /* Set arg (the union) to the address of the storage location for */ 
   /* returned semid_ds value */ 
   arg.buf = &sem_buf; 
   if (semctl(sem_id, 0, IPC_STAT, arg) == -1) { 
      perror ("semctl: IPC_STAT"); 
      exit(2); 
   } 
   printf ("Create %s", ctime(&sem_buf.sem_ctime)); 
   /* Set arg (the union) to the address of the initializing vector */ 
   arg.array = sem_array; 
   if (semctl(sem_id, 0, SETALL, arg) == -1) { 
      perror("semctl: SETALL"); 
      exit(3); 
   } 
   for (i=0; i<NS; ++i) { 
      if ((sem_value = semctl(sem_id, i, GETVAL, 0)) == -1) { 
         perror("semctl : GETVAL"); 
         exit(4); 
      } 
      printf ("Semaphore %d has value of %d\n",i, sem_value); 
   } 
   /*remove semaphore */ 
   if (semctl(sem_id, 0, IPC_RMID, 0) == -1) { 
      perror ("semctl: IPC_RMID"); 
      exit(5); 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Have you identified the line where the exception occurs? If not, you could try to use a debugger, or sprinkle a few `printf("line %d\n", __LINE__);` statements around. It'd help us all to figure out what goes wrong.

Comment: You forgot to `#include <time.h>` and that warning is definitely major.

Comment: Adding `#include <time.h>` made the problem go away! Thank you. However the semaphore identifier is still 0, is that supposed to happen?

Comment: If in doubt, read the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/shmget): "A valid segment identifier, shmid, is returned on success, -1 on error."

Comment: `0` is a valid ipc id and the most likely after rebooting your system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include `time.h` to the compiler recognize `ctime` function. The warning is because the compiler don't know `ctime` is a function and that returns an `char*`. By default GCC assumes the unknown function returns an `int`.